# InlineEditing with knockout array

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js

I´m trying to integrate Craig Cavaliers [liveEditor](https://craigcav.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/simple-inline-editing-with-knockoutjs/) solution with an array, but cannot get it to work.

My HTML is a simple  foreach-loop:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: myArray">
    <li>      
        <div data-bind="liveEditor: message">
            <span class="view"><a href="#" data-bind="click: message.edit, text: message() || 'Click to edit message 1'"></a></span>
            <input class="edit" data-bind="value: message, 
                                enterKey: message.stopEditing, 
                                selectAndFocus: message.editing, 
                                event: { blur: message.stopEditing }" />
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Heres my viewModel:

```
var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.myArray = ko.observableArray();
    var newmsg = new Message({
        ID: 1,
        message: 'first message'
    });

    self.myArray.push(newmsg);
    newmsg.message('2nd string');
    self.myArray.push(newmsg);
};
```

Craig´s bindingsHandlers is the following:

```
ko.extenders.liveEditor = function (target) {
    target.editing = ko.observable(false);

    target.edit = function () {
        target.editing(true);
    };

    target.stopEditing = function () {
        target.editing(false);
    };
    return target;
};

ko.bindingHandlers.liveEditor = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        observable.extend({ liveEditor: this });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        ko.bindingHandlers.css.update(element, function () { return { editing: observable.editing }; });
    }
};
```

And finally the css:

```
.edit {
    display: none;    
}
.editing .edit {
    display: block;    
}
.editing .view {
    display: none;
}
```

Full fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AsleG/ujgn1tq8/

Where do I go wrong with this?

Comment: You're going wrong by not reading the console: 1) you haven't included KnockoutJS, 2) you can't use github as a CDN. Include your links from a CDN like http://cdnjs.com. If the library is not there, you'll have to upload it somewhere yourself (as probably for the `liveEditor` 'plugin'. Test with this advice and see if it works.

Comment: @Tyblitz there's also https://rawgit.com/

Comment: I have never understood where´s the console on jsfiddle...? Regarding knockout it is set as framework. even changing this to an external resource doesn´t change anything. And liveEditor is not a plugin, all the code is there with the bindingHandler and the extender.

Comment: @janfoeh I know, but the `app.js` script @Asle G was using in the previous versions of his fiddle, eg see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AsleG/ujgn1tq8/4/) is not valid: http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/architecture-examples/knockoutjs/js/app.js. @Asle G forgot to check the libraries loaded in Fiddle Options, so yes indeed, Knockout was there, my bad. And you don't have a jsFiddle console AFAIK, just open the default browser console

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was quite simple. It had nothing to do with lacking libraries; it was solely down to the fact that defining my viewmodel as a function demanded it to be instanciated in the applyBindings. 
´"new viewModel"´ is the new viewModel.